# Open List of URLs in Different Tabs and Click Same Button

Tags: javascript

I'm totally new to this but looking for a solution.  I have a list of 50 unique URLs that I need to open in individual Chrome tabs and then click the same button twice on that page.  The first prompts a popup for the second.  Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: Not without doing it in a browser extension or userscript running in an extension like TamperMonkey...or setting up a server side headless browser routine to do it. This whole question is far too broad for Stackoverflow as per the guidlines in the [help]

Answer (score 0):

If this is within the browser you may want to look into [userscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript). However, if it isn't then you should update your tags to include shell scripting.

Without any code or some more information on your application its hard to say.